# Does android, specifically the HTC Incredible, support headphone volume buttons?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, headphones

Coming from the IPhone, I love being able to control my phone from my wired 3 button headphones.  Center clicking to start/stop music or answer calls and using the 2 volume buttons to adjust the volume without pulling the phone out of my pocket.

I've tried different 3 button headphones with my HTC Incredible and can answer calls and pause and play audio with the center button, but I've never been able to change the volume from my headphones buttons.

Are volume adjustments via headphones supported in the HTC Incredible?  Am I just using the wrong headphones?

Comment: They are supported by Android in general, not sure about the Incredible though.  Of course it's dependent on the headphones as well.

Comment: Have you tried the headphones that come with the actual handset?

Comment: No headphones came with my HTC Incredible.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely supported by Android, and I'd be incredibly surprised if the Incredible didn't support volume control.

I had no problem using the volume control buttons in the headset I bought for my G1. I bought mine on eBay for $7, it has no branding but was marketed as explicitly for the G1. It uses the USB plug, not the 3.5mm plug.

You might need a USB headset.

There is something specific about apple's 3.5mm jacks that doesn't play well with non-apple devices. Something about the placement of the insulating plastic bands. It is described in the answer to: [Why can't I use my iPhone Headphones with my HTC Thunderbolt?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/why-cant-i-use-my-iphone-headphones-with-my-htc-thunderbolt)

So it wouldn't surprise me if a headset from your iphone with a 3.5mm jack would not work on your Incredible. But if you buy a headset manufactured for the incredible (Ebay and Amazon appear to have plenty) and the volume controls *still* don't work, the problem is probably your device.

Comment: Specifically on the incredible (I have one), the headset button is supported, as is the mic, the volume buttons are not. It's an OS level problem, not a mic jack problem as both HTC and Apple have identical [pinouts](http://pinoutsguide.com/HeadsetsHeadphones/blackberry_9700_headset_pinout.shtml) and the contact points in the jack itself are in the same places.

Comment: [Android API reference for the media (headset) button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone volume buttons are not supported by the Android framework. If you want to control the volume you'll need headphones like [these](http://store.androidcentral.com/htc-stereo-headset-with-remote-controller/11A29A7399.htm) in combination with an app like [Headset Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=tvk.headvol).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to give those a try

Answer (score 2):

If it is a hardware issue you might be able to get the results you want with an app I found called [Headset Button Controller](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton&feature=search_result).  It's a couple of bucks in the Market but there's a trial version as well that they suggest you use for testing.  [Here's the trial version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headset).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the app and wasn't able to get it to recognize my volume buttons.  I still really would like to know if the HTC Incredible support headphones and if so, which brands.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR - The play/pause button is supported and works (fairly) well. The volume buttons are definitely not supported.

I have an OG Incredible, and [Klipsch S4i headset](http://www.klipsch.com/image-s4i-black-in-ear-headset). The mic works and the play/pause button works. The volume buttons do not. You can remap the play/pause button with [headset droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=tvk.headvol) as was mentioned before.

Unfortunately, the performance of the headset button is frustratingly inconsistent, especially if you have apps that attempt to listen for the headset button intent (amazon mp3, poweramp, google listen, etc). When an app is running and playing a media file, it will generally deal with the headset button press in the way it is configured, but not always (sometimes instead of pausing the currently playing media file, it will launch another app that listens for the intent and start it playing). Google listen is especially badly-behaved on my phone, not surprising since it's been abandonded.

My advice is get a headset you like (the Klipsch headset produces really excellent sound, especially compared with the Apple and HTC offerings) and play around with the different apps.