# Will any headset work with android?

Tags: headphones

I'm looking for a good headset, preferably with mic, answer button and volume controls.  I see iPhone compatible everywhere but no mention of Android compatible.  Do they use the same specifications, and do I need to worry about compatibility when buying a wired headset?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/why-cant-i-use-my-iphone-headphones-with-my-htc-thunderbolt

Answer (score 1):

Headsets with mic, answer button and volume controls which are iPhone compatible, in general, will not work with Android headsets. The mic and the sound will work, but the buttons will not.

Headset with mic and only one button will work without problems.

Comment: Are there any with more buttons that will work with Android phones?

Comment: Sadly I'm not aware of any 3rd party headsets.

Answer (score 0):

Android phones mostly use the standard layout of the 3,5mm jack, but there are some special cases. For example, Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 uses a slightly different jack than Galaxy S. The difference is barely visible by the naked eye, but when I use the Tab headset in Galaxy S, the music sounds like it's mono, not stereo and the answer button doesn't work. I'd advise you to test before buying if possible in order to eliminate any unfortunate surprises.