# Using an iPhone headset on a HTC One V

Tags: headphone-jack, headset, htc-one-v, headset-controls

Is an HTC One V fully compatible with an iPhone headset? [This site](http://www.accessorygeeks.com/htc-one-v-headphones.html) seems to indicate it is, but questions [like](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14924/will-any-headset-work-with-android) [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/why-cant-i-use-my-iphone-headphones-with-my-htc-thunderbolt) have me worried. Would it work with an [app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66266/why-no-consistent-headset-control/79081)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the HTC One V specifically, but in my experience, the Mic, stereo ouputs, and the single button answer/stop will work for both Apple and (most if not all) Android phones.  But the volume up/down buttons will not work, even with an app such as headphone button controller; it simply does not get detected.

The problem arises when the marketing depts start using a word such as "compatible", meaning a degree of compatibility, but not necessarily every function.  So they feel OK saying an Apple headphone is compatible, meaning just the audio works, or even the audio and the answer button.

However, it is possible that the HTC can somehow detect and use these extra two buttons, I suppose, but I would guess not.